# clipping semi-circle from bitmap

Tags: android

I'm trying to clip a semi-circular chunk out of the bitmap so that it looks like this

[image]   [image]

The problem I'm having is correctly scaling the arc (so that its smaller than bitmap) and positioning it on the left edge. If I try to draw the arc in the other quadrant `path.arcTo(rectF, 180-30, 60)`, then the concavity is pointing the wrong way.

```
        Canvas c = new Canvas(sshotBitmap);

        Path path = new Path();

        RectF rectF = new 
                RectF(0, 0, (int)((float)social.getWidth()), social.getHeight());

        path.reset();
        path.arcTo(rectF, -30, 60);  
        path.close();
        c.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        social.draw(c);
```

Comment: It'd probably be easier, and more intuitive, to use the `Path#addCircle()` method instead, and center it at `(0, c.getHeight() / 2)`.

Comment: @MikeM. Post as answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using arcs can be somewhat cumbersome. Since you just need a semicircular clip, an easier, and possibly more intuitive, solution would be to use the `Path#addCircle()` method instead, and center it on the middle of the left side of the Canvas. That is, center it at `(0, c.getHeight() / 2)`.